# Series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_k$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}b_k$ converge but $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{b_k}{a_k}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

EDIT: The are many good, simple examples to try here, but I want to understand this "hint," given below, opaque as it is.

I'm working on an existence proof that shows two series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_k$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}b_k$ converge but $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{b_k}{a_k}$ diverges.

So I need $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}$ with $M >0$ $\exists$ $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k \gt N$ we have $\frac{b_k}{a_k} \gt M$.

My hint is to construct an increasing sequence $(N_j)$ such that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=N_j}a_k \leq \frac{1}{j^3}$ and to let  $b_k = ja_k$ for $Nj \leq k \leq N_{j+1}$.

Good. Then the sequence (a_k) can be broken down into blocks, with $\{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{N_1-1}\}$ less than some M, and the subsequent blocks less than $\frac{1}{j^3}$. So we have a way to estimate the sum: $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_k \leq  M + \sum^{\infty}_{j+1}\frac{1}{j^3}$.

I'm befuddled because I can't figure out how this information about the sums relates to the convergence of $\frac{b_k}{a_k}$ unless there's some test that I'm not thinking of. I thought to construct sequences out of the partial sums, but that seems counter-indicated by the phrasing of the prompt.

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: Why so complicated? What about $a_k = 1/k^3, b_k = 1/k^2$ ?

Comment: Unrelated to this particular problem, but is there a reason that you *never accepted* an answer to your questions so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about accepting answers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I was unaware of that feature. I knew we could up-vote, but not accept answers.

Comment: @MartinR To your original suggestion, echoed below, we have convergence of $a_k$ and $b_k$ by the p-series test, and then it is simple to show the ratio diverges. I have no idea why the "hint" was so complicated. I've mucked around in it quite a while. But I do* want to understand the long way round, too.

Answer (score 4):

One example where both $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}$ diverge would be

$$a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}\sin \left(\frac{n}{2}\right),\ b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}\sin\left(n\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the given hint particularly helpful. Instead, think of it in the following way: if it were true, then that would imply that whenever $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge, the quotient $a_n/b_n$ has a nonzero limit.

This is too strong to be true: As in Martin R's comment, Take any two examples of convergent series, say
$$\sum _{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}, \quad \sum _{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}$$
or
$$\sum _{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}, \quad \sum _{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$
There are plenty of counterexamples.

---

The hint allows you to show that for *all* convergent $\sum a_k$ with $a_k > 0$ there exists a convergent series $\sum b_k$ such that $a_k/b_k$ diverges. Indeed:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty b_k
& = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \sum_{k=N_j}^{N_{j+1}-1} b_k \\
& = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty j \sum_{k=N_j}^{N_{j+1}-1} a_k \\
& \leq \sum_{j = 1}^\infty j \cdot \frac{1}{j^3} \\
& < \infty
\end{align*}$$
while we have
$$\frac{b_k}{a_k}\geq j$$
for $k \geq N_j$ so that $\frac{b_k}{a_k} \to \infty$.

Comment: How is this more helpful than the hint? It is precisely what the hint says.

Comment: Huh? The hint says: "[...] construct an increasing sequence $(N_j)$ such that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=N_j}a_k \leq \frac{1}{j^3}$ and to let  $b_k = ja_k$ for $Nj \leq k \leq N_{j+1}$. "

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought you were referring to the hint given in the first comment. Anyway, given this comment, your answer is redundant.

Comment: I don't know. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559

Comment: Yes, I see. Well, for the sake of fairness, in a case like this where an answer is posted which doesn't provide more than a comment already given, the comment should be referenced.

Comment: I wouldn't mind myself in this case, with the question being elementary. Especially when somebody takes the time to write down an answer, their thoughts, and give another example. IMO, reputation is not only earned for being clever, also for making the effort to write an answer. Which is why I don't like the idea of community wiki if there isn't any collaboration. Answer edited.

Comment: I almost agree. I just think that you should never use "elementary" or also "trivial" in an argument as this can be offensive and is very subjective.

Comment: Right, I agree.

Comment: I was hoping somebody might address the "hint" even though or maybe especially because it seems like over-kill. This is the kind of prompt I'm up against when exams come, and I'm trying to understand my prof's way of thinking, as I often get marked down when I over-simplify things and miss nuances.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum a_i$ be a convergent series and let $a_i\not=0$. Let $b_i=a_i$. Then $\sum b_i$ is also convergent series and $\frac{a_i}{b_i}=1$. So -- counterexample.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question, which asks for an example where $\frac{b_k}{a_k}$ diverges, not a proof that it always does.

Comment: Right, I want $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_k}{a_k} = \infty$.